# CacheLookup property in Ax 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

I created some elements in an already existing `base enum`, when I open the form to enter some records and to select the values in `lookup`, I can't see my elements until and unless I clear the cache.

Every time I want to create a record, I have to clear the cache first.

I tried restarting `client`, Restarting `AOS`, but nothing helps.

I checked the tables `Cache lookup` property and its selected to `Entire table`. Please help in resolving the issue, do I have to change the `Cache Lookup` property or it can be handled through some other way???

Answer (score 3):

Try to clear user cache - .auc files located on the client machine.